# Getting an audio file from a streaming PHP script in an HTML5 video tag

Tags: audio, video, php, streaming, html5

I'm trying to download the raw audio file from a specific site.

The page contains the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
            <source src="http://site.com/sound.php?id=1&amp;stream" type="audio/mpeg">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of a raw file, the file is being provided via the PHP script. And just trying to open that PHP file results in it redirecting back to the main page.

Is there a way to get around this? I've never seen this kind of technique before.

Comment: It’s set to be streamed (probably [with](http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets) [DASH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video)), not downloaded. Have you tried using a video-downloading site or tool?

Comment: Not yet, I want to do it in-browser, not using anything 3rd party. (I'm using Safari on a Mac). Or from a command line script, if possible...

Comment: I also want to know the solution itself, not just an app that makes it work. For example, there might be a way to form a request that makes the PHP file think it's coming from the HTML5 video player and pipes the bytes to a file on the command line. I don't know how that would work though. cURL might be able to do it but I'm not sure how, specifically how to make it give up the proper byte stream instead of just redirecting back to the home page.

Comment: That won’t work if it’s streaming; you would have to actually stream it and keep the data. That’s what video-downloading programs do; browsers don’t (neither the HTML5 module of the browser, nor Flash). Technically, using a video-downloading site *would* be “in-browser”. If the video site is one that the downloading site supports, then they will have a mapping or something to determine how to access the actual video file, but chances are that if it is a DASH streaming video, that it would be supported.

Comment: There's the rub... the browser, during the interpretation of the HTML5 video tag, is sending particular HTTP requests to get the data from that URL somehow. The PHP file returns the bytes that make up the file. Every time I make an HTTP GET request using cURL, it always returns a 302 and redirects to the homepage. I want to try to simulate the HTML5 video tag and capture the data coming from the stream but I can't figure out how to do it. And whatever kind of streaming they're using, I don't think it's DASH. (If it is, how would I know, and how would I access the file)?

Comment: From what I've seen of DASH, you need to place a manifest file in the video tag... that's not there, just the PHP file. The HTML snippet I provided above is the _whole_ page, including headers. There's no JavaScript, nothing else on the page, just what's shown. It's also not a site supported by any video download services.

Comment: You could try using a packet-sniffer to get a glimpse into the data being transferred back and forth (even [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) would suffice for basic monitoring).